# HttpWebRequest memory leak issue with Newtonsoft

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, json.net, out-of-memory, httpwebrequest

I have an application that calls an API via the below function.

```
    Public Function CreateWebRequest(ByVal strURL As String) As JArray
        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Method="GET"
            request.ContentType = "application/json"
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
            Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                Dim reader As StreamReader
                reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim rawresp As String
                rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Dim array As JArray = JArray.Parse(rawresp)
                reader.Close()
                response.Close()
                Return array
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim empty As New JArray
            Return empty
        End Try
    End Function
```

I noticed recently that sometimes I get a timeout on my server (Taking too much time to respond). Digging more into details, I wanted to check if I have a memory leaking issue with the function I used to call the API.

Is there anything wrong in the above function? Do I need to close any connection or clear any memory that I haven't done?